# How does CLR get notified to trigger garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

We know that the CLR triggers a garbage collection (GC) when it detects that generation 0 has filled its budget. This is the
most common trigger of a GC. But how does the CLR get notified?

To put it in an concrete example, let's say I have an application that has allocated a lot of objects on heap:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item> {new Item(), new Item(),....};

... // Do something else

items.Add(new Item()); // <------------ This makes the generation 0 budget full
```

But the source code of `List<T>`'s `Add` method doesn't do any special thing. It just add an item to the list, not calling any internal API to notify CLR "hey, I'm new'ing an object. Please check if it will exceed the generation 0 budget"

So there must be a dedicate thread or process that constantly monitor the heap, so when an application thread new up an object that exceed the budget, this dedicate thread or process can detect it. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, then what's the name of this thread/process? Could someone provides more information?

Comment: Have you checked this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions-for-a-garbage-collection ?

Comment: @Christos yes but it doesn't say how CLR get notified that it need to trigger a GC? the link you post is just an overal generalization description, I want the details how CLR get notified when we new up objects which might exceed the generation 0 budget

Comment: Not "when it detects that", the trigger is that your program "has attempted to allocate"... Every `new` allocation must go through the runtime's allocator. The allocator may pause the thread to GC and return the new memory block.

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is where the object got its memory from. What was responsible for allocating space in memory for the `Item` instance you constructed.

Comment: There are other GC triggers too, like explicitly calling GC's Collect method, windows reporting low memory condition, CLR unloading AppDomain, CLR is shutting down.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the obvious. When you add a new object to the list, that object has to be created. When an object is created you're interacting directly with the CLR and its memory manager. At that point the CLR has to check if there's enough room for the object or if it has to do anything. If it has to trigger a GC at that point, it does so and emits ETW messages announcing the collection.

Comment: thanks for your answer. As my understanding, CLR needs to execute on its own thread, so does it mean that whenever application new up a object, there is a thread context switch, switch between application thread to CLR thread, then CLR checks if the new object exceeds the budgets, if no then another thread context switch from CLR thread back to application thread?Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I haven't kept up with the implementation details, but I don't think allocations are moved to a dedicated thread. I don't see the point of doing so. I assume that when an allocation occurs, your code simply calls into CLR code that does the allocation and possibly triggers a collection. The finalizer runs on its own thread though. Perhaps that's what you're talking about?